# Как я могу уйти от статического метода, который либо лезет в пул, либо создает объект?

Tags: c#

В общем, есть перечень классов, которые имеют приватный конструктор и геттеры наружу.

Объект создается через статический метод `Get`, который внутри себя заглядывает в статический класс с пулом объектов и если нету свободного объекта, то создает новый и проводит некоторую инициализацию и возвращает этот объект, а если он берется из пула, то какие-то поля перезаписываются и возвращается этот готовый для работы объект.

Я думал думал, как это организовать красивее и чтобы было равнозначно, но на ум ничего не пришло.

Под равнозначностью я имею ввиду, что объект напоминает структуру, где в процессе жизни объект нельзя изменить (если только он не валяется в пуле свободных объектов), а Get возвращает новый объект.

Comment: Возвращать из пула обертку, которая позволяет только читать свойства у оригинала и делегирует все оригиналу.

Comment: А как положить объект назад в пул? Ведь получается, что все будет сокрыто за оберткой. Если дать возможнось получить из обертки исходный объект, то пропадает неизменяемость... Тут нужен какой-нибудь пример, как выстроить иерархию.

Comment: Совсем скрыть от клиента не получится. Нужен явный способ сказать, что объект уже не нужен. Либо создать у объекта явный метод (такое применяется например в пулах соедениний к БД, там есть метод типа `close`) либо реализовать IDisposable.Dispose. Реализация в обертке вернет оригинал в пул.

Comment: Возможно, стоит посмотреть примеры в Вики: [Object pool pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), [Объектный пул](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Объектный_пул), а также классы [ArrayPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.buffers.arraypool-1?view=net-6.0), [ObjectPool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.objectpool.objectpool-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)